# Почему небезопасно хранить данные в файле?

Tags: php, файлы, безопасность

Всем известен факт, что хранить закрытую информацию в файлах небезопасно. Я сделал проект, где данные (куки и другие) хранятся в файлах. Папка с такими файлами имеет непрогнозируемое название, файлы имеют непрогнозируемое название и расширение, доступ к папке производится исключительно на стороне сервера, в папке прописан  .htaccess, поэтому я на сегодняшний день не вижу возможности получить к папке несанкционированный доступ. 
Какие скрытые (неизвестные мне) способы существуют чтобы вот так просто взломать такую папку на сервере?

Ссылка на проект (не сочтите за пиар) - http://js-games.hol.es

Comment: Разместите папку с файлами вне web директории сервера и спите спокойно!

Comment: Не все хостинги предоставляют такую возможность.

Comment: Очень хороший вопрос. Если кто-то соберется написать о том что security through obscurity  - это чушь собачья и детский лепет, то это будет очень полезный ответ для всех юных энтузиастов.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Кто вам сказал, что информацию в файлах хранить небезопасно? А в чем хранить? Если вы посмотрите на строение любого хранилища или базы данных, все ваши данные - это файл. Специального формата, требующий действий для получения из него данных, по возможности защищенный криптографическими алгоритмами. Записали вы свои сессии предположим в файловое хранилище с доступом по паролю и что? Злоумышленник получил доступ к серверу и открыл ваш конфиг, где этот ключ лежит.

**Небезопасно - это хранить эти файлы в системе которая не соблюдает основные методы защиты.**

### Неясность - это еще не безопасность

> В Москве на Ходынском поле рабочие во время ремонта дороги повредили
> кабель специальной связи, который не был указан в документации в связи
> с большой секретностью расположения кабеля. Это хорошая иллюстрация
> того, что при использовании принципа «безопасность через неясность»
> безопасность может быть нарушена не только злоумышленником, но даже и
> случайным человеком

Товарищ **@Ипатьев** верно заметил, что обеспечение безопасности **только** через неясность - детский лепет, а точнее **очень короткий промежуток** времени перед окончательным взломом и то, что вы сделали, лишь усложнило работу с данными для Вас, но не для хакера. Поиск ваших файлов через специальное ПО при доступе на сервере не займет много времени. Например, если вы запихнули базу данных в одну из миллиона папок, но на нее не стоит пароля, я как хакер предположу, что она весит больше всех остальных файлов, и отсортирую файлы по размеру.

### Используйте комплексный подход

Создавая сайт, используйте **комплекс методов защиты от НСД на ваш сервер**: директория с данными вне доступа для пользователя, все порты на сервер закрыты, кроме 443 и 80, ssh-доступ ограничен ключом, и ключ хранится в безопасности, скрипты не дают возможности выполнять произвольные команды на сервере и выходить за пределы ограниченной директории, использовать надежные пароли, скрипты не выполняются от root, ПО стоит из проверенных и надежных источников и т.д.

В целом это позволит вам избежать НСД в 99 процентах случаев.

**Будем честны, все можно взломать, и это лишь вопрос времени.**

Любая система безопасности, в принципе, может быть вскрыта. Эффективной считают такую защиту, стоимость взлома которой соизмерима с ценностью добываемой при этом информации.

В некотором случае, вас может подвести хостинг-провайдер, который использует старое ПО, не соблюдает правила безопасности, и не поставил обновление, исправляющее возможность кражи виртуальных машин (см. атаки на гипервизор).

Вы не защищены от этого, и можно купить сервер, самому все настроить, нанять специалиста, выделить отдельную сеть внутри дата-центра, на одном сервере хранить файлы, на другом сервере в другом дата-центре хранить ключи, все и везде шифровать и т.д, нанять полк с танками, которые будут бегать вокруг стойки, но вопрос в том, сколько стоят данные, которые вы защищаете?

**Не будет ли система защиты дороже, чем стоимость потери ваших данных?**

Comment: А как же запись в файл во время краха системы, отключения сервера. Можно кучу данных потерять, если не все. В базах данных есть защита от этого. И от многого другого, например, от нескольких попыток записи в файл одновременно. Тоже можно потерять данные. Хуже будет если после подобной операции конфиг станет некорректным.

Comment: @pank В любом случае, под словом "безопасно", мы понимали в данном вопросе конфиденциальность данных, а не их целостность. Указанные вами процедуры, также можно легко соблюдать и при записи в файл, другой вопрос, что их нужно написать, а в СУБД это уже реализовано. База данных не панацея для надежного хранения данных, данные можно потерять, если оборудование содержит дефекты или используется неправильно. В последнее время оборудование оснащено доп.питанием, которое позволяет завершить запись и не получить битые файлы.

Answer (score 1):

Во-первых, закрытая информация не должна храниться нигде в открытом виде (требования нормативов)

Во-вторых, есть вещи, типа атак обхода директорий (Directory Traversal) и т.п.

В-третьих, Вы доверяете защиту серверу (его владельцу). Если с его стороны что-то глюкнет, он извинится, а Вы потеряете...

Comment: Было бы интересно посмотреть результат Directory Traversal на примере моего сайта, чтобы я явно убедился в  потенциальной опасности.